# Multiple Tkinter Objects together

Tags: python, tkinter

My game user interface is roughly designed like this

(1) class Game Start: contain multiple inputs like who start, what color, ect

(2) class Game Board: contains current score and current board

(3) class Game Over: contain final score and board

(4) class Application: does all the calling

I have the game logic completed so it will not be in this module. Would it be a good idea to have a Main Tkinter Window in the Application that will be continually replaced by the different above Tkinter objects?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for a question like this

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass each Game from Frame and .pack and .pack_forget each as appropriate.  Or .grid all three in the same cell and .lift each as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one main application class that creates the main window. Depending on how you want the GUI to work, the other classes should either inherit from `Toplevel` (if you want them to be floating windows) or `Frame` (if you want them to be embedded in the main window.

The other alternative is for all but the main class inherit from `object` or some other non-gui class. As part of their `__init__` can can create whatever widgets they need.